# I keep getting the wrong numbers from my program

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to write a program where the user inputs 2 dates and the program calculates the days in between (without using any of the calendar classes) and prints the results, but I keep getting crazy numbers that make no sense. When I tried to make it calculate 5 days it printed the results of 333 and when I try to do something like 20 years it prints numbers in the millions.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DaysCalc {

public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);



System.out.print("Please enter starting date (mm-dd-yyyy) ");
String startingdate = input.next();

System.out.print("Please enter ending date (mm-dd-yyyy) ");
String finishingdate = input.next();

String startingdayst = startingdate.substring(3, 5);

String startingmonthst = startingdate.substring(0, 2);

String startingyearst = startingdate.substring(6, 10);

String finishingdayst = finishingdate.substring(3, 5);

String finishingmonthst = finishingdate.substring(0, 2);

String finishingyearst = finishingdate.substring(6, 10);

int startingyear = Integer.parseInt(startingyearst);
int startingday = Integer.parseInt(startingdayst);
int startingmonth = Integer.parseInt(startingmonthst);
int finishingyear = Integer.parseInt(finishingyearst);
int finishingday = Integer.parseInt(finishingdayst);
int finishingmonth = Integer.parseInt(finishingmonthst);

System.out.println(startingyear + "," + startingday + "," + startingmonth );
System.out.println(finishingyear + "," + finishingday + "," + finishingmonth);

int daysLeft = 0;

int daysUntilEnd = 0;

int i = 0;

daysLeft = daysInAMonth(startingmonth, startingyear) - startingday;
daysUntilEnd = finishingday;

for (int monthCount = startingmonth + 1; monthCount <= 12; monthCount++)
{
i += daysInAMonth(monthCount, startingyear);
}       
for (int yearCount = startingyear + 1; yearCount <= finishingyear; yearCount++)
{
    if (isLeapYear(yearCount))
    {
        i = i * 366;
    }
    else
    {
        i = i * 365;
    }
i += daysUntilEnd;

}
    System.out.println(i);
}
private static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
     boolean isLeapYear = ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0));
     return isLeapYear;
    }

private static int daysInAMonth(int month, int year) {
    if (month == 2) 
    {
        if (isLeapYear(year) ) 
        {
            return 29;
        }
        else 
        {
            return 28;
        }

    }
    if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 9 || month == 11) {
        return 31;
    }
    return 30;
}
}
```

Comment: As you can’t use any in-built classes (which would make this easy); one can only assume this is homework. So try debugging line by line and see the values in real time and you’ll quickly see what part is causing the issue.

Comment: September and November have 30 days; the last time I checked anyway. And what is i * 365 etc. supposed to achieve? Don’t you mean to add rather than multiply?

Comment: Please provide the inputs you tried.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was with this part

```
for (int monthCount = startingmonth + 1; monthCount < finishingmonth; monthCount++)
    {

    i += daysInAMonth(monthCount, startingyear);
    }       

    for (int yearCount = startingyear + 1; yearCount <= finishingyear; yearCount++)
    {
        if (isLeapYear(yearCount))
        {
            i = i + 366;
        }
        else
        {
            i = i + 365;
        }


    }
    i += daysUntilEnd;
    i += daysInAMonth(startingmonth, startingyear)-startingday-1;
        System.out.println(i);
```

it's not completely bug free but i hope it helps you to see where it went wrong. it was kind of an eye mistake